# Pysdl2 on OSX How to prevent beachball cursor during long iteration loops

Tags: python, sdl, sdl-2, pysdl2

Even after calling `sdl2.mouse.SDL_ShowCursor(0)`, which effectively hides the cursor during runtime, when doing lengthy iterations (for my purposes, loading a large volume of images into RAM), the beachball cursor nonetheless appears.

It is critical that this doesn't happen because what I'm writing is an experiment for coginitive psychology on visual attention—this kind of visual distraction absolutely cannot occur.

Comment: Sounds to me as if you are loading the images in the main thread, which causes the application to become unresponsive to system events and which in turn leads to the beachball cursor.

Did you try to load the images in a seperate process or thread? Or to regularly process the event loop while loading the images?

Comment: I should have answered my own question because, indeed, pumping the event queue solved my problem. If you want to put your comment as the answer I'll mark it correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself by calling sdl2.SDL_PumpEvents() once per loop.